# Why are all my pages, posts, custom fields gone, even though the count is still there?

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a custom theme in WordPress 5.3. I updated my local database with my staging database but now all of my pages, posts, custom fields, etc are gone. The count says they are there and when I switch to the theme TwentyTwenty, they all appear again. This is what I am seeing. If I change the name of my theme folder, everything works correctly, but as soon as I change it back to what it was called, it doesn't work again.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VEJA.png)

Answer (score 0):

FYI -

I had a broken function in my function.php file